# Inline css on vue component

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm trying to apply a background-color on a div in vue and I'm able to pass in a hex_code from my data but I want to apply a `rgba` styling to the background. Is there something wrong with my syntax here?

```
      <div
        v-for="item in itemList"
        :style="{ 'background-color': `rgba(${ item.hex_code }, 0.5)` }"
        :key="item.id">
     </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `rgba(hex, opacity)` is not allowed in CSS (but it is possible in SCSS), it has to be `rgba(red, green, blue, opacity)`. You want something like:

```
:style="{ 'background-color': `rgba(${ item.red }, ${ item.green }, ${ item.blue }, 0.5)` }"
```

See also [conversion between RGB and hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb).

**Edit**: Since you are doing this in a bound attribute, you can define a helper function to convert your `hex_code` to RGB suitable for CSS:

```
:style="{ 'background-color': `rgba(${hexCodeToCSSRGB(item.hex_code)}, 0.5)` }"
```

With this helper function (adapted from the linked answer):

```
function hexToRgb(hex) {
  var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
  return result
    ? `${parseInt(result[1], 16)}, ${parseInt(result[2], 16)}, ${parseInt(result[3], 16)}`
    : "0, 0, 0";
}
```

Note that this will convert `"#ff00aa"` to `"255, 0, 170"`, so in your `background-color`, you would end up with `rgba(255, 0, 170, 0.5)`.